# Transfer funds from a PayPal linked account

Tags: paypal

It is possible to programatically transfer funds (debit and credit) between PayPal and its associated bank account ?

To be more precise; PayPal X has bank account Y associated with it. 
Is it possible to programatically transfer funds between them (without the need to initiate the transfer at the eBanking of account Y) ?

Thank you in advance

Eduardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API that will do this, however, if you call PayPal and request that they enable "auto-sweep" for you, it will automatically transfer your PayPal balance to your bank at the end of each day.

Comment: I was more after the other way around. Transferring from the associated bank account toward the paypal. Paypal has the Withdrawal funds functionality. So you mean that even that is not available in their API ?

Comment: The withdrawal funds is not available via an API,no.  If you're wanting to pull out of the bank then would happen automatically if you submit a payment via the API with no funds in the PayPal account.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It seems I will have to look for another solution